# IAM Service Account Key vs Google Credentials File

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I'm writing code to generate and download a private key for a Google Cloud service account.

Using the IAM API, I was able to [create a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts/create), and my call to [generate a key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys/create) seems to be working. I get back a Service Account Key as described on the [IAM API create key page](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys#ServiceAccountKey), like

```
{ 
  "privateKeyType": "TYPE_GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_FILE",
  "privateKeyData": "random-key-stringkajdkjakjfke", ...
}
```

I downloaded this file as a JSON response and am trying to authenticate with it:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=service-account-key-file.json
```

Unfortunately, I get an error stating
`The .json key file is not in a valid format.`

When I go though the Google Cloud Console flow (IAM & Admin -> Service accounts -> ... -> Create Key -> Create) I get a downloaded JSON file that looks like

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "private_key": "----BEGIN-PRIVATE-KEY-----",
  "auth_uri": "https://gaiastaging.corp.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
}
```

This file looks completely different than the response from the IAM API. Explains my error! Unfortunately, this format doesn't seem to be described anywhere. It's mentioned briefly in some [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/common/auth). Is it a Google Credentials File?

I'd like to take the IAM response file/JSON and convert it to the second credentials file. I've tried writing some code to convert it, but there are some fields like `"auth_provider_x509_cert_url"` that I don't understand.

Perhaps converting the file is the wrong approach as well? More generally:

How can I generate a file and then use it to authenticate with gcloud?

How should I describe/distinguish between both of the above files? Why is each type of file useful?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

About the two files:

A Google Credentials file and a Service Account Credentials file are the same thing - they're both the second type of file that I downloaded off the Google Cloud Console page. No great official docs pages on them, but they're referenced a lot. Probably also Application Default Credentials.

The JSON response from the IAM create call - this is just a response to an API call. It's not useful outside of parsing it with your application code.

To generate a Google Credentials file:

In the JSON response to the IAM create, there's a field `privateKeyData`. This field actually **contains the entire Google Credentials file**. It's just encoded as a base64 string. I just downloaded the file from HTML as

```
<a href="data:attachment/json;base64;charset=utf-8,THAT-LONG-privateKeyData-base64-string-here" download="service-account-key.json">
  Download key
</a>
```

Or if you just want to confirm that it contains all the information quickly, copy paste the base64 `privateKeyData` field into a file `google-credentials` and decode it (on Linux) with:

```
base64 -d google-credentials
```

I was then able to run

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=google-credentials.json
```

and got

```
Activated service account credentials for: [service-account-id@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great to know and is NOT anywhere on the line.