# Convert base64 encoded google service account key to JSON file using Python

Tags: python, base64, google-compute-engine

hello I'm trying to convert a google service account JSON key (contained in a base64 encoded field named privateKeyData in file foo.json - more context [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys) ) into the actual JSON file (I need that format as ansible only accepts that)

The foo.json file is obtained using this google python api [method](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/iam/v1/python/latest/iam_v1.projects.serviceAccounts.keys.html#create)

what I'm trying to do (though I am using python) is also described [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291205/iam-service-account-key-vs-google-credentials-file) thread which by the way does not work for me (tried on OSx and Linux).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import base64

with open('/tmp/foo.json', 'r') as f:
    ymldict = json.load(f)

b64encodedCreds = ymldict['privateKeyData']

b64decodedBytes = base64.b64decode(b64encodedCreds,validate=True)

outputStr = b64decodedBytes
print(outputStr)

#issue
outputStr = b64decodedBytes.decode('UTF-8')
print(outputStr)
```

yields

```
./test.py 
b'0\x82\t\xab\x02\x01\x030\x82\td\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\x07\x01\xa0\x82\tU\x04\x82\tQ0\x82\tM0\x82\x05q\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\x07\x01\xa0\x82\x05b\x04\x82\x05^0\x82\x05Z0\x82\x05V\x06\x0b*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\x0c\n\x01\x02\xa0\x82\x#TRUNCATING HERE
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./test.py", line 17, in <module>
        outputStr = b64decodedBytes.decode('UTF-8')
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I think I have run out of ideas and spent now more than a day on this :(

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your base64 decoding logic looks fine to me. The problem you are facing is probably due to a character encoding mismatch. The response body you received after calling `create` (your foo.json file) is probably not encoded with UTF-8. Check out the response header's `Content-Type` field. It should look something like this:

```
Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=Shift_JIS
```

Try to decode your base64 decoded string with the encoding used in the content type

```
b64decodedBytes.decode('Shift_JIS')
```

Comment: thank you for your help Mug4n. I've tried running that `create` method with tcpdump on all I can see grepping (can't seem to filter on that connection specifically) shows Content-Type with charset utf-8... :(

Comment: it is now working and funny enough I have no idea what changed.thanks again

Comment: privateKeyData was starting with "MII...." when I was hitting the issue. now I get back "ewo....." . god knows what happened here